# Hibernate JPA difference in remove between find() and merge()

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I want to ask what is the difference between removing using find() and merge() method. I get the same results after compiling. User class and UserDetails are classes in OneToOne relation (parent and child).

using find()

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    User temp = entityManager.find(User.class,user.getId());
    entityManager.remove(temp.getUserDetails());
    entityManager.remove(temp);
}
```

using merge()

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    User temp = entityManager.merge(user);
    entityManager.remove(temp.getUserDetails());
    entityManager.remove(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The merge() method is used to perform an update on an entity passed as a parameter, after the update is done it returns the result of the update/merge, this is why you was able to use it as a "find()" method.

The find() method only takes an ID as a parameter so it's not possible to perform an update with this one.

I would says that the merge() method is less effective because it will perform the update first then return the result, maybe there's also some logic to check if the entity is dirty or not before performing the update which can result in an additional cost. On the other hand, there shouldn't be a huge difference between the two methods in most scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I rather wanted to know what are the pros/cons of using them and which one is better to use :)